# How can i get information from a Task httpResponse?

Tags: c#, winforms, task, httpresponse

I'm calling an API with an async methode, the method returns the information i need in a task but i can't display the information i need in a textbox of a winform.

Here is the methode :

```
public static async Task<Token> GetTokenAsync()
        {
            Token token = new Token();
            string path = @"URL";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //URL + HEADER DE LA REQUETE
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(path);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //MIS EN FORME DU JSON D'AUTHENTIFICATION
                var requestBody = new
                {
                    username = "DSAE_PHID_RECETTE",
                    password = "testpwd1"
                };

                //ENVOIE DE LA REQUETE ET RECUPERATION DE LA REPONSE
                HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(client.BaseAddress, requestBody);

                //RECUPERATION DES INFORMATION DU RETOUR DE L'API
                if (apiResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var response = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    token.idToken = response;
                    return token;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }

            }
```

And here is the attempt to display

```
 private void btnEnvoyer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task<Token> tokentask = RequeteHttp.GetTokenAsync();

           // txtResult.Text = tokentask.Result.ToString();

        }
```

If i uncomment the ligne it freezes.

I know there something with the Task i don't fully understand but even with all the exemple i can't make it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this Winforms?

Comment: Hi Amy, yes it s a winform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are the rare place, where you are allowed to use an `async void`. So you should try something like this:

```
private async void btnEnvoyer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var token = await RequeteHttp.GetTokenAsync();
    txtResult.Text = token.ToString();
}
```